# Why do my tests pass using a "wrong" JK flip-flop model?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, testbench

I have a testbench written for a JK flip-flop. Below I have the correct circuit that passes the testbench and another circuit which passes the testbench as well. Is there something wrong with my testbench?

a) Correct JK flip-flop:

```
module jk_ff (input j, input k, input clk, output logic q);
    always @ (posedge clk)
       case ({j,k})
          2'b00 :  q <= q;
          2'b01 :  q <= 0;
          2'b10 :  q <= 1;
          2'b11 :  q <= ~q;
       endcase
 endmodule
```

b) Wrong JK flip-flop, but it passes all test cases in the testbench:

```
module jk_ff (input j, input k, input clk, output logic q);
 always @(posedge clk)
 case ({j,k})
 2'b10 : q <= ~ q ;
 2'b01 : q <= 0 ;
 2'b11 : q <= 0 ;
 endcase
 endmodule
```

c) Testbench

```
include "jk.sv"

module tb_jk();

    // open fitness file
    int passedFile;

   reg j;
   reg k;
   reg clk;
   wire q;

   always #5 clk = ~clk;

   jk_ff    jk0 ( .j(j),
                  .k(k),
                  .clk(clk),
                  .q(q));

   initial begin
    // open file
    passedFile = $fopen("passed.txt", "w");

      clk = 0;
      j = 0;
      k = 1;

      #10 if(clk == 1 && j == 0 && k == 1 && q == 0) $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 1);
         else $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 0);
      #10 j = 0; k = 0;

      #10 if(clk == 1 && j == 0 && k == 0 && q == 0) $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 1);
            else $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 0);
      #10 j = 1; k = 0;

       #10 if(clk == 1 && j == 1 && k == 0 && q == 1) $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 1);
             else $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 0);
      #10 j = 1; k = 1;

      #10 if(clk == 1 && j == 1 && k == 1 && q == 0) $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 1);
            else $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 0);

      #10 $finish;

      // close file
      $fclose(passedFile);
   end
endmodule
```

Comment: Part of asking any question is explaining what you expect to happen versus what you are actually seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is something wrong with your testbench.  You are currently checking the output (`q`) every *other* clock cycle, but you should check it every clock cycle.

One way to check on every clock cycle (at the negedge as in your checker) is to add this code to the bottom of your testbench:

```
logic q2;
always @(posedge clk) begin : good
    case ({j,k})
        2'b00 :  q2 <= q2;
        2'b01 :  q2 <= 0;
        2'b10 :  q2 <= 1;
        2'b11 :  q2 <= ~q2;
    endcase
end

always @(negedge clk) begin
    if (q === q2) begin
        $display($time, " pass q=%b", q);
    end else begin
        $display($time, " fail q=%b q2=%b", q, q2);
    end
end
```

You should see a `fail` at time 60.

`q2` is a model of your known-good jk_ff.

Comment: Thanks for this. Why do I have to include the correct circuit in the testbench. Can I do without it and have a robust testbench that prints 1 and 0 if a circuit passes or fails a testcase respectively. So say if I have four testcases I want to know how many of that testcase a circuit passes and failed out of the total number of testcases in the testbench.

Comment: And why do we have to make the check at the negative clock edge?

Comment: `module jk_ff (input j, input k, input clk, output logic q); 
 always @(posedge clk) 
 case ({j,k}) 
 2'b10 : q <= 1 ; 
 2'b11 : q <= ~ q ; 
 2'b01 : q <= 0 ;
 endcase 
 endmodule`
This circuit passes the new testbench though.

Comment: It was just a suggestion.  Use whatever checking code you want.  The negedge is where your testbench is checking.  The point is that your checker was incomplete.  Do you agree?  If you have a new circuit which is now failing, then you need to adjust your checker model again.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I don't know which other  assertions to add to complete and make the testbench robust enough to test these circuits properly. Thanks again.