# How to improve the system verilog testbench for JK flip flop

Tags: verilog, homework, system-verilog

I have a system verilog module as shown in (a) which passes the testbench in (b) but this should be the case as this is not the correct implementation. Correct implementation shown in (c). I am missing anything or any suggestions. Also, in my testbench I will like to get rid of the correct JK flip flop code block as the current testbench is dependent on it.

a)

```
module jk_ff (input j, input k, input clk, output logic q); 
 always @(posedge clk) 
 case ({j,k}) 
 2'b01 : q <= 0 ;
 2'b10 : q <= 1 ;
 2'b11 : q <= ~ q ;
 endcase 
 endmodule
```

b)

```
`include "jk.sv"

module tb_jk();

    // open fitness file
    int passedFile;

   reg j;
   reg k;
   reg clk;
   wire q;

   logic q2;

   always #5 clk = ~clk;

   jk_ff    jk0 ( .j(j),
                  .k(k),
                  .clk(clk),
                  .q(q));

   initial begin
     $dumpfile("test.vcd");
     $dumpvars;

    // open file
    passedFile = $fopen("passed.txt", "w");
    //if(!passedFile) $display("error");
    //if(passedFile)
    //  $display("file opened");
    //else
    //   $display("couldn't open the file");

      clk = 0;
      j = 0;
      k = 1;

      #10 if(clk == 1 && j == 0 && k == 1 && q === q2) $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 1);
         else $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 0);
      #10 j = 0; k = 0;

      #10 if(clk == 1 && j == 0 && k == 0 && q === q2) $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 1);
            else $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 0);
      #10 j = 1; k = 0;

       #10;  if(clk == 1 && j == 1 && k == 0 && q === q2) $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 1);
             else $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 0);
      #10 j = 1; k = 1;

      #10 if(clk == 1 && j == 1 && k == 1 && q === q2) $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 1);
            else $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 0);


      #10 $finish;




      // close file
      $fclose(passedFile);
   end


   always @(posedge clk) begin : good
       case ({j,k})
           2'b00 :  q2 <= q2;
           2'b01 :  q2 <= 0;
           2'b10 :  q2 <= 1;
           2'b11 :  q2 <= ~q2;
       endcase
   end

   always @(negedge clk) begin
       if (q === q2) begin
           $display($time, " pass q=%b", q);
           //$fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 1);
       end else begin
           $display($time, " fail q=%b q2=%b", q, q2);
           //$fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 0);
       end
   end
endmodule
```

c)

```
module jk_ff ( input j,
               input k,
               input clk,
               output q);

   reg q;

   always @ (posedge clk)
      case ({j,k})
         2'b00 :  q <= q;
         2'b01 :  q <= 0;
         2'b10 :  q <= 1;
         2'b11 :  q <= ~q;
      endcase
endmodule
```

Earlier post [Testing JK Flipflop using system verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/495196/250301)

Comment: This question does not seem to be significantly different from the last question you posted, and you accepted an answer to that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may seem absurd to replicate your DUT code in your testbench. But there's little else you can do for such a trivial design. But jump up to a counter or a multi-stage multiplier and it's much easier to see the benefit of predicting your design's output versus having to manually look at file or waveform and ***see*** if the test is passing or falling by inspecting every time. You want a "PASS" or "FAIL" at the end of running the test.

Your predictor does not have to fit into the confines of synthesizable RTL. You can write code that takes the current values of q,j, and k and predicts what the next value of q should be.

```
logic q_prev;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    q_prev = q; #1;
    case ({j,k})
      2'b00: assert (q==q_prev);
      2'b01: assert (q=='0);
      2'b10: assert (q=='1);
      2'b11: assert (q==!q_prev);
    endcase
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the design in (a) above manages to pass the testbench you provided. Unless it is a correct alternative impementation of JK flipflop (it missed the `2'b00 signal`).

Also, which other way would you advice  such a testbench to be written.

Comment: ` 2'b00 : q <= q ;` is unnecessarily redundant in RTL. If you don't make an assignment to a variable in some branches, the variable *must* retain its value.

Comment: @dave_50, with such redundacy in RTL in place, it is possible certain circuits may pass all testcases in the testbench even when they shouldn't. For example these circuits ```module jk_ff (input j, input k, input clk, output logic q); 
 always @(posedge clk) 
 case ({j,k}) 
 2'b00 : q <= 0; 
 2'b10 : q <= ~q; 
 default : q <= 0; 
 endcase 
 endmodule``` and ```module jk_ff (input j, input k, input clk, output logic q); 
 always @(posedge clk) 
 case ({j,k}) 
 2'b00 : q <= 0; 
 2'b10 : q <= ~q; 
 default : q <= 0; 
 endcase 
 endmodule``` pass all testcases in the testbench.

Comment: @dave_50 I finally got the testbench to be robust enough by testing each transition twice; this made it possible for the circuits I posted earlier to be passing all testcases to fail some of them. Thanks.